# js.dart scoped() undefined

Tags: javascript, dart

I am trying to get this test program

```
import "package:js/js.dart" as js;

main() {
  js.scoped();
  js.retain();
  js.hasProperty();
  js.map();
  js.array();
}
```

to compile, but the dart editor (1.1.0.dev_04_00) is flagging scoped() and retain() as undefined, which is contrary to what I'm told by the [js.dart documentation](http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js.html).  The other three functions (hasProperty(), map(), and array()) are not flagged as undefined (and are flagged as being used incorrectly), so I'm assuming the problem is not that the editor doesn't know about js.dart, or that the editor and the package are somehow out of sync.  What is the explanation for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of the js package](http://dart-lang.github.io/js-interop/docs/js.html) is outdated. `scoped` has been deprecated in *0.0.26* and removed in *0.1.0*.

**EDIT** : The documentation has been updated.